# MS Access- Having a field to insert an image

Tags: windows, image, ms-access, ms-office

my doubt is simple today, the answer, might not be that simple as I can't figure it out on my own.

How can I have a field on an access form where the user can input an image?

The idea is simple, on the company i work for, there has been a database for my co-worker to fill every time there is a repair on our products to be done.

What he asked me recently is if I can change the database to include a field where he would select a picture he had taken of the damaged goods and add it to the database, so every record on the db would have a picture, ideally hosted on the company's NAS

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OLE field, and set its type to linked, but this way require NAS with SMB support(windows shared folders or SAMBA) in order to store images at it.

Comment: thank you, this helps, the company's nas has been giving lots of problems lately, i will probably use some sort of cloud to store the pictures.
But the main thing here is creating the field.
This OLE field set to linked should do it, thank you for your help, if it does not fit my requirements i will have to bother you again :p

Comment: remember that linked or embedded choice is for each object not for field type. So you can mix them if needed.